# Installing self signed certificate does not resolve security error in Windows 7

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, windows-7, certificate

I am developing a C# application which consumes a test version of a 3rd party WCF service where the server has a self signed cert. Up until now I have taken a sledgehammer approach in the setup of my integration tests of:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

However I'd now like to make things available for UAT testing.

I have tried adding the cert to my Trusted Root Certification Authorities as detailed here:

http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2012/04/rights-management-how-to-get-windows-7-to-trust-a-self-signed-server-certificate.html

Following these instructions the cert gets added to the store but I'm still getting a "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

I've noticed that the "issued to" and "issued from" values are different in the cert - could this be causing the the problem?

Also, I stepped back to see if I can simply get trust to work at simply the browser level when navigating to the service URL but this generates a SSL error too.

In the end I don't care about the SSL error as it will be resolved when we switch to using a live server but I don't want to put the kludge in production code.

Any thoughts on:

1. the reason why installing the cert fails to resolve the failure to connect?
2. ways I might resolve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, in our past experience (especially with self-signed certificates) we have seen the “Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel” error for two primary reasons:

- The certificate was not properly saved in the certificate store
- The url and certificate had a “name” mismatch

Since you seem to have tried a few certificate store locations, your issue may be a name mismatch. The following link explains the name mismatch.
http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/certificate-name-mismatch-error.htm

Regards,

Comment: You should also check the dates of the cert: make sure the start isn't in the future or the end isn't in the past.